# Zip plugin is not capable of showing internal files content after upgrade

Tags: plugin-zip

```
    vim --version
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Oct 21 2021 10:39:53)
    macOS version - x86_64
    Included patches: 1-3550
    Compiled by Homebrew
    Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
    +acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
    +arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       -tcl
    +autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
    +autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
    -autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
    -balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
    +balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
    -browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
    ++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
    +byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl              +title
    +channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   -toolbar
    +cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
    -clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
    +clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
    +cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
    +cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
    +cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
    +comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
    +conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
    +cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
    +cscope            +localmap          +ruby              +wildmenu
    +cursorbind        +lua               +scrollbind        +windows
    +cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
    +dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
    +diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            -xfontset
    +digraphs          +mouse             -sound             -xim
    -dnd               -mouseshape        +spell             -xpm
    -ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xsmp
    +emacs_tags        -mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
    +eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
    +ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax
    +extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
    -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
       system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
         user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
     2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
          user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
           defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
      fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
    Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN -g -O2 -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
    Linking: clang -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lm -lncurses -liconv -lintl -framework AppKit -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.4 -mmacosx-version-min=11.3 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -L/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-darwin -lpython3.9 -framework CoreFoundation -lruby.3.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.0.2_1/lib
```

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.6.1
- Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0
- unzip, zip and vim were installed with the help of brew package manager
- previously I have been using Vim 8.0 and zip plugin version v28. After upgrade I can list the content of zip files, but I cannot see the content of any internal file. I see the empty content for any internal file
- current version of Vim is 8.2 and zip plugin is v31

steps to reproduce:

```bash
echo "hi" > test.txt
zip test.zip test.txt
vim test.zip
# then try to open test.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This might be better as an issue on the GitHub or mailing list… I'm not sure what [vi.se] can do with this, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to check if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a known problem.

In a meantime, I have found a workaround. Installing neovim helps to work with zip-files. Though, it does not solve the problem with vim.

Comment: issue is confirmed: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/8974

Comment: @AlexeyDral Please post a self answer with your findings from reporting the bug?

Comment: @filbranden issue is fixed. It will be released with v32 zip plugin, commit: https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/519cc559b08b800edc429688aece7ad6a00d41eb#diff-c3431e35dce9ef0098df28d227c4539fc744a55e32dca0291be3eeddab0fe245